# handleChange Function not firing on click... Reactjs checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm mapping over a group of checkboxes in an effort to check and uncheck boxes with a handleChange function, but I can't see why it won't work. I think it's a small error and I've hit maximum fatigue. Please lend me your eyes and minds. As they say, "The mind is useless when the eyes are blind."

Code below:

```
    /* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
/* eslint-disable no-shadow */
/** @module templates/GeoidCaculator/components/Models */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CheckBox from 'components/GeoidCaculator/components/CheckBox';

/**
 * @description Creates the field selection view as well handles the state for the checkboxes.
 * @param {}
 * @returns {Object} Returns Fields jsx.
 */
function Models() {
    const [check, setCheck] = useState({});
    /**
     * @description Handles the state for the checkboxes.
     * @param {event}
     * @returns {Object} Returns boolean values.
     */
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setCheck({ ...check, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
        console.log('check: ', check);
    };


    const checkboxes = [
        {
            name: ' 2020',
            key: 'checkBox1',
            label: '-2020',
        },
        {
            name: ' 2008',
            key: 'checkBox2',
            label: '-2008',

        },
        {
            name: ' 1996',
            key: 'checkBox3',
            label: '-1996',
        },
        {
            name: ' 1984',
            key: 'checkBox4',
            label: '-1984',
        },
    ];

    console.log(checkboxes.map((item) => item.key), handleChange, 'hello render');

    return (
        <Col className="col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <Row className="modelText">
                <span>Select a Model:</span>
            </Row>
            {checkboxes.map((item) => (
                <Row className="modelRow">
                    <label
                        key={item.key}
                        htmlFor="model-id"
                        className="checkbox-inline checkbox-styled checkbox-success"
                    >
                        <button type="button">
                            <CheckBox name={item.name} checked={check[item.name]} onChange={handleChange} />
                            <span>{item.name}</span>
                        </button>
                    </label>
                </Row>
            ))}
        </Col>
    );
}


export default Models;

    /** @module templates/GeoidCaculator/components/CheckBox */
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

/**
 * @description Creates the checkbox inputs and sets initial state.
 * @param {sting} type - declares checkbox
 * @param {sting} name - declares name
 * @param {boolean} checked - boolean value to check/uncheck box
 * @param {Event} onChange - hanldes change
 * @returns {Object} Returns input jsx.
 */
const CheckBox = ({
    type, name, checked, onChange,
}) => (
    <input type={type} name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
);

CheckBox.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    checked: PropTypes.bool,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

CheckBox.defaultProps = {
    type: 'checkbox',
    checked: false,
};
```

export default CheckBox;

Comment: i think you are missing `type` prop on `CheckBox` when you are mapping through the `checkboxes` array

Comment: I test this code and I it woks, the only change I made was replace the Col and Row components with a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is your `htmlFor` prop for `label`. This needs to be mapped with an `id` for an `input` field. Refer here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label.

So for that, I recommend refactoring your `CheckBox` component such that it would also take in an `id` prop (you can also just opt to use `key` instead of passing `id` as prop).

```
const CheckBox = ({ id, type, name, checked, onChange }) => (
  <input id={id} type={type} name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
);
```

And on mapping, again, the `htmlFor` value needs to be partnered with its corresponding `input` field.

```
<label
  key={item.key}
  htmlFor={item.key}
  className="checkbox-inline checkbox-styled checkbox-success"
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.target.closest("label").click();
  }}
>
  <button type="button" style={{pointerEvents: "none"}}>
    <CheckBox
      id={item.key}
      type="checkbox"
      name={item.name}
      checked={check[item.name]}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <span>{item.name}</span>
  </button>
</label>
```

Finally, pay attention to the `style` prop of `button`. Clicking `label` will click its descendants such as `button` or `span`. That style will prevent the those from getting clicked so that the label would be the element clicked therefore the checkbox's change event will trigger.

[image: Edit runtime-river-0ow2h]

Comment: Thanks @95faf8e76605e973 the htmlFor id was the issue. I did test without the style={{pointerEvents: "none"}} prop on the button and the behavior is still as desired. All that prop is doing is preventing the button and span from being clicked as descendants of the label right? What is the advantage?

Comment: i see. your CSS might have solved that issue on its own. there is no other advantage other than to make the label be the element clicked. you can see an example of the issue on my sandbox when you take out the pointer-events style